# Texture map morphing

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I am doing 3D code archeology. My original code, written > 10 years ago in OpenGL + XMLisp did a [nice morph of Mona Lisa](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~ralex/papers/PDF/AVI08_end-user_visualizations.pdf) with only about 30 lines of code. The code is in Lisp and will probably not help much ([in this google code grave](https://code.google.com/archive/p/xmlisp/)). But at the core is a mesh tessellating the image including two vertices that are controlled through a "happiness" variable:

This works really well but I like to rewrite this in three.js without rolling my own shader. As I have looked through the documentation I just don't know where to even start. I just need a triangle mesh keeping the xt, yt texture coordinates constant but changing the x, y to morph the image.  I can't imagine this should be much larger in three.js

In case you wonder what this is really used for. We used this technique to create a nice simulation of a human anatomy in real time morphing illustrations from Gray's Anatomy: Sadly, only low res youtube video left: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39NJJC1Vt18

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show original code in text form as well as any attempts at solving

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty straightforward.

You make

`var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("YourImage.png")}));`

add it to your scene... then get `plane.geometry.vertices` and warp them manually, and then do a `plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true` to get your changes to reflect back onto the GPU.

If you want some 1 on 1 help, feel free to join our three.js slack channel and post something in #general :)

Cheers!

https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI

Comment: You might want to elaborate who "our" is with respect to the slack channel. ***I*** know (or at least am moderately certain) that you're a three.js contributor, but that doesn't mean everyone does. IMO, it would be better to post a link to the slack channel as listed on threejs.org (https://threejs-slack.herokuapp.com/) than a random invite.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the basic [Geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry) class. Make some triangles:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 )
);
geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push(
    new THREE.Vector2( 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 1, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 0, 1 )
)
```

Then morph it:

```
geometry.vertices[ 0 ].set( 2, -1, 400 );
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```